# Need help simplifying expression

Tags: calculus

I have this expresson that I have to simplify. I have been trying for quite a long time but I always get stuck. Could you give me some tips what steps to use? I would also be happy for the final result so I can have something to check my work.

$$
E(x,y):=\bigg(\frac{x^{-1/6}-\frac{5}{\sqrt[6]{y}}}{\frac1{x^{1/3}}-y^{-1/3}}-5\cdot\frac{x^{-1/6}-y^{-1/6}}{x^{-1/3}-\sqrt[3]{y^{-1}}}\bigg)^{-1}\cdot\frac{6\sqrt[6]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{y}}
$$

Comment: First step could be to regulate the use of fraction exponents or radicals, and/or to relieve terms of negative exponents.  We would appreciate some evidence of effort.

Comment: hint: $\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $a:=x^{-1/6},\,b:=y^{-1/6}$ the expression becomes$$\left(\frac{a-5b-5(a-b)}{a^2-b^2}\right)^{-1}\frac{6/a}{1/a^2-1/b^2}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{-4a}\frac{6ab^2}{b^2-a^2}=\frac32b^2=\frac32y^{-1/3}.$$

Comment: This is definively a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

In a first step i would write
$$\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{x}}-\frac{5}{\sqrt[6]{y}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{y}}}\right)$$
$$-5\times\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{y}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{y}}}\right)$$
The first term is given by
$$\frac{\sqrt[6]{y}-5\sqrt[6]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{y}-\sqrt[3]{x}}\times\frac{\sqrt[3]{xy}}{\sqrt[6]{xy}}$$